# Extract numbers from cells containing mixed alpha-numeric strings

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have one column that looks like this:

```
      A
1 om2222prakash
2 kumar83566
3 222gsrana
4 k4566hhhh23
```

How can I find out only numeric data in A1, A2, A3 and A4? I am using Microsoft Excel 2007, and would like to have the output look like this:

```
      A
1 2222
2 83566
3 222
4 456623
```

Comment: Hi @OmPrakash, and welcome to SuperUser! I cleaned up your question a bit, and I hope I got the right message across

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel: Remove only alphabetic characters (retain special characters)](http://superuser.com/questions/702746/excel-remove-only-alphabetic-characters-retain-special-characters)

Answer (score 3):

Well, open VBE (Visual Basic Editor) with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>. In the VBA Project Explorer right click and add a *`Module`*.

Copy and paste the below code and hit <kbd>F5</kbd> to run the macro.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetNumbers()

    Dim uColumn As String

    ' if your data is in a different column then change A to some other letter(s)
    uColumn = "A"

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, r As Range
    For i = 1 To Range(uColumn & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set r = Range(uColumn & i)
        Dim tmpStr As String
        tmpStr = vbNullString
        For j = 1 To Len(r)
            If IsNumeric(Right(Left(r, j), 1)) Then tmpStr = tmpStr & Right(Left(r, j), 1)
        Next j
        r.NumberFormat = "@"
        r = tmpStr
    Next i

End Sub
```

There's a variable named *`uColumn`*. It has `A` currently assigned as the column. If your data sits in a different column then change from `A` to your column letter(s)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

Here is a formula that should work.

```
=1*MID(A1,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(1*MID(A1,ROW($1:$9),1)),0),COUNT(1*MID(A1,ROW($1:$9),1)))
```

The reference in ROW() needs to be altered to include all the rows of data you would like considered (referenced twice in the formula).   So for example, if your last row of data is 200 it would read ROW($1:$2000).

If your alpha numeric data is in `A1` then place this formula into `B1` and hit shift+enter (this is an array formula).
This will take only the numbers from A1 and place them in B1. Drag the corner of B1 down to the bottom of your data to auto fill for the rest of your data.

You should see your alpha numeric data in Column A and only the numbers from that data in column B allowing you to do as you wish with them.

Comment: I tried this and was unable to get it to work.  What is the purpose of "ROW($1:$9)" ?

Comment: didn’t work. #N/A

Answer (score 1):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(AR81,"0",""),"1",""),"2",""),"3",""),"4",""),"5",""),"6",""),"7",""),"8",""),"9","")
```

Replaces specified characters in a string with alternate characters.  In the example numeric are replaced with blanks,  it should work with other things like special characters.

Comment: Please reread the question.  The objective is to leave only the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Following the substitute logic, you would use the following to remove letters and symbols.  If I missed any, all you need is a quick modification following the same pattern.

You will need to change the starting cell (it's `A2` in the sample below below).

`=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(A2),"A",),"B",),"C",),"D",),"E",),"F",),"G",),"H",),"I",),"J",),"K",),"L",),"M",),"N",),"O",),"P",),"Q",),"R",),"S",),"T",),"U",),"V",),"W",),"X",),"Y",),"Z",)," ",),".",),"(",),")",),"-",),"+",),"=",),"!",),"@",),"#",),"$",),"%",),"^",),"&",),"*",),"_",),"[",),"]",),"{",),"}",),"\",),"|",),":",),";",),"""",),"<",),">",),",",),"?",)`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone searching the issue after 2021:

I like the `VALUE(MID())` approach. Simple and straightforward.

```
=VALUE(CONCAT(IFERROR(VALUE(MID(A1,ROW(1:32767),1)),"")))

=VALUE(CONCAT(IFERROR(VALUE(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(A1)),1)),"")))
```

The `MID()` collects the characters in the string into groups of 1. Nowadays the second version, using `SEQUENCE()` would be best for `MID()`'s starting points as it will ONLY make `MID()` make as many 1 character length strings as needed, not the whole 32,767 it MIGHT need, but the first version's `ROW(1:32767)` works due to the limit on cell contents length.

`VALUE()` returns numeric characters and errors for anything else. Note that since the data showed only positive integers being of concern, these formulas do not make allowance for decimal values or negative values (though a negative value's "absolute value" would be preserved).

`IFERROR()` changes the errors to "blanks" (`""`).

`CONCAT()` puts those elements together into a single string. Simpler than `TEXTJOIN()`, though admittedly not by a lot.

At this point, if the desired result is a string, not a formal number, one would stop. For the point of usability, Excel will actually handle it as a number anyway in any function where using a string makes no real sense. A way in which this might be useful is in a lookup, if the lookup key is all strings, as a number being looked up might not work. But to get it treated as number, wrap it all with the final `VALUE()`.

I cannot say it would have worked before dynamic arrays AND the changes that came along with them as I have the updating version and cannot test for that. That, and the fact that `CONCAT()` with its ability to handle array (range) addressing was not available in 2013, means this would not have worked then even with the `ROW(1:32767)` instead of `SEQUENCE().

But people searching for solutions to this kind of problem TODAY would probably be best served by a formula that works, and also uses the "latest and greatest" so-to-speak.

For more complicated delvings into strings, `MID()` can collect characters into groups larger than a 1 character. Can be handy, though less so than single character groups. One example, related to this question, might be that one needs to extract a number (doesn't have to be a number, just in keeping with the question here) of exact known length (as in even if that length is not the same for every cell, there is some way to know the exact length) as one could form groups of that length and test via `VALUE()` (or a different test that works for the situation if it is not a number one is seeking). Naturally, if the number itself is known, a simple `SUBSTITUTE()/LEN()` test would be best, but if only the length is known, then the `VALUE(MID))` idea kicks in.