# Excel: Remove only alphabetic characters (retain special characters)

Tags: microsoft-excel, visual-basic

Two datasets to compare.

6701.2345_5432     and on the second the system inserted letters.   6701E.2345_5432

I have about 8000 rows I need to compare and I can't seem to modify the VBA code to remove alphas without removing the special characters I need to retain.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

This VBA code uses RegEx to remove alphabetic characters from all  cells on the active sheet.
Change `[A-Za-z]` to whatever should be removed.

```
Sub RegExRemove()

    Dim RegEx As Object
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    RegEx.Global = True

    RegEx.Pattern = "[A-Za-z]"
    For Each objCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
        objCell.Value = RegEx.Replace(objCell.Value, "")
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Minor revision to use only selected cells

Sub RegExRemove()

```
Dim RegEx As Object
Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
RegEx.Global = True

RegEx.Pattern = "[A-Za-z]"
For Each Cell In Selection()
   Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = RegEx.Replace(Cell.Value, "")
Next
```

End Sub